# How can pipes and grep and wc be combined to just give a count of the phrase “syntax ok”

Tags: unix, grep, wc

How can pipes and grep and wc be combined to just give a count of the phrase “syntax ok”

Something like the following…

```
cd /usr/IBMIHS/bin/ |
apachectl -t -f /usr/IBMIHS/conf/AAA/httpd.conf |
apachectl -t -f /usr/IBMIHS/conf/AAA/siteAA.conf |
grep "^Syntax OK" | wc
```

Comment: I've no idea what `apachectl` does but `cd /usr/IBMIHS/bin/ |` doesn't make sense - ITYM `;`, not `|`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply via grouping commands with curly brackets, and use `grep -c`:

```
{
    apachectl -t -f /usr/IBMIHS/conf/AAA/httpd.conf
    apachectl -t -f /usr/IBMIHS/conf/AAA/siteAA.conf
} |& grep -c "Syntax OK"
```

From `man grep`

> -c, --count
> Suppress  normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file.  With the -v, --invert-match option (see below), count non-matching lines.

Comment: Getting a count of 0.

Comment: So add the example output of `apachectl -t -f /usr/IBMIHS/conf/AAA/siteAA.conf` I use `nginx`

Comment: > man use    
Manual entry for use not found or not installed.    
> which nginx    
no nginx in /usr/bin /etc /usr/sbin /usr/ucb /home/websvcd/bin /usr/bin/X11 /sbin

Comment: Or try without the anchor `^` so : `grep -c "Syntax OK"`

Comment: Paste the output of `apachectl -t -f /usr/IBMIHS/conf/AAA/siteAA.conf`

Comment: The following have been tried.   1) fgrep -c '^Syntax' grep -c 'Syntax'

Comment: .
[Thu Jan 19 15:15:15.525318 2023] [so:warn] [pid 26935558:tid 1] AH01574: module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping
Syntax OK

Comment: If you are using `bash` as shell, this should work with my edited answer

Comment: > echo $BASH_VERSION
5.0.18(1)-release

Comment: @paulhr this code does exactly what you asked for. If you're not getting the output you expect then debug each line of code in your question as THAT is where the problem is, not this code that shows how to combine them.